# C# replace recursive with while loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, recursion, while-loop, foreach

We have a node tree from a system, the `Node` model is like

```cs
Public class Node {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public bool HasChildren { get; set; }
  public List<Node> Children { get; set; }
}
```

So, based on the `Node` model, the JSON of the node tree will be something like below:

```json
{
  "Name": "Root",
  "HasChildren": true,
  "Children": [
    {
      "Name": "Node-1",
      "HasChildren": true,
      "Children": [
        {
          "Name": "Node-1-1",
          "HasChildren": false,
          "Children": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Name": "Node-2",
      "HasChildren": true,
      "Children": [
        {
          "Name": "Node-2-1",
          "HasChildren": false,
          "Children": [
            {
              "Name": "Node-2-1-1",
              "HasChildren": false,
              "Children": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "Name": "Node-2-2",
          "HasChildren": false,
          "Children": [
            {
              "Name": "Node-2-2-1",
              "HasChildren": false,
              "Children": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
    ...
  ]
}
```

Now, I'd like to save every node in a flattened array or list. To traverse all the nodes, I know I can recursively get them. But, using recursion causes a big usage of memory. 
Is there a way of using the loop logic, like `while`, `for`, or `foreach` logic to do the same?

Comment: *"Is there a way..."*. Almost certainly. What have you tried and where are you stuck? This site is not a place where you tell us what you want and we write the code for you. Consider the logic required, make you best attempt to implement that logic in code and then, if it doesn't work, show us what you've done and explain exactly what the issue with it is.

Comment: better change coding logic to your needs?

Comment: It is not true that recursion uses more memory than other methods of parsing.  There is some small amount of overhead memory that is used when you call a method.  Recursion can method many times but the amount of memory isn't huge.  The size of the tree structure should not be inside the recursion methods and will be the same if recursion is used or recursion is not used.

Comment: The recursive solution would use the stack to remember where you're up to. A loop will need some other data structure to remember that. Using the stack has advantages, as you can easily mix data types together without any extra heap allocations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this code, you can do it in a loop:

```
List<Node> result = new List<Node> { node };
        bool finished = false;
        int start = 0;
        while(!finished)
        {
            int end = result.Count;
            for(int i = start; i < end; i++)
            {
                if(result[i].HasChildren)
                {
                    result.AddRange(result[i].Children);
                }
            }
            
            if(result.Count == start)
            {
                finished = true;
            }
            start = end;
        }
```

First, we add the root node to the result list. Then we enter a loop, which has another loop in it. This inner loop goes through all entries which have been added in the last iteration. In the first iteration, the inner loop goes only through the root node. The inner loop adds then all children of those nodes to the result list. The outer loop will run until the inner loop doesn't add any further nodes.

Note that it will change the order of the flattened list. The children of a node won't be directly behind their parent. Instead, the more down a node is in the hierarchy, the more in the end of the list the node will be. I hope this is ok for you, since you didn't write anything about your preferred order.

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Rx67kK

Comment: The ordering of this can be called "Breadth-first". Also, all children will be placed behind their parent, but not *immediately behind*.

Comment: Thank you @SomeBody, I do like this solution and your explanation. It does what exactly I want to achieve. Thank you again!

Answer (score 3):

My goto tree iterator looks like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DepthFirst<T>(T self, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> selector)
{
    var stack = new Stack<T>();
    stack.Push(self);
    while (stack.Count > 0)
    {
        var current = stack.Pop();
        yield return current;
        foreach (var child in selector(current))
        {
            stack.Push(child);
        }
    }
}
```

Called like `DepthFirst(myRootNode, n => n.Children)`. This generic, so it can be reused for all different kinds of tree representations. It is also lazily evaluated.

This variant iterates in a depth first order, but it is trivial to change the stack to a queue to get a breadth first ordering.